# What are some ways to fill a small gap between a wooden column and a concrete wall

Tags: wood, caulk, pergola, gap, wood-filler

I have wood pergola columns connecting to my house through fixtures which are fitted into grooves in the wood. The wood was cut slightly too short (or due to small variations in the wall), there is a small gap about 1–2 centimeters in some places. I want to fill the gap so that the metal fixture won't be visible and the wood "end" will be flush with the wall so water won't get between the column and the wall.

In this picture you might be able to see the small gap I need to fill. In some other places the gap is larger (in this case it might be barely visible)

[image]

Comment: Is the slot in the ends of the wood cut in from the top or bottom of the cross beams?

Comment: The slots are cut from the top of the wood about 3/4 the depth of the beam so that they aren't visible from beneath

Comment: If you are worried about water getting at the end of the beam what is your plan to deal with the water intrusion into the slots from the top?

Comment: there is plastic sheeting http://www.palram.com/suntuf on top of the wooden beams and some aluminum guards around the perimeter (ontop of the plastic) which makes sure water doesn't fall through the gaps between the plastic and the wall. Its purely an aesthetic issue to solve

Comment: Ok. Since it is purely an aesthetic issue then if you try out the trim idea I placed in my answer you would only want to place it on the sides and bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to correct for the gaps is a challenge if you just decide to "stick something in there" such as caulk or shims. I say that because anything you do along those lines is going to look crappy and kludged up.

The best solution would be to do a re-install by carefully measuring each individual piece and cutting it to the correct length. Done that way then a very small bead of exterior type caulk can be used to seal off the end of the beam to the wall if needed.

One possible solution that may work for the existing installation is to get some trim pieces that are cut and fitted around the ends of the beam and up to the wall to cover the gap. It would look something like this:

[image]

The trim pieces could then be sealed to the wall with caulk if so needed.

Comment: Tha is a really good idea. I could try to cut some wood pieces like that

Comment: I do not know the type of wood you used for the beams but you may want to select a trim made of a wood known to last a long time outdoors such as a cedar or redwood.

Comment: For convenience and best look you may also want to consider a ready milled piece of trim wood that you buy in a long length. Then you just need to cut your pieces to length with chop saw.